# Picasa API returns different XML when requested with Ajax

Tags: ajax, cordova, google-plus, picasso

I'm creating a Phonegap app for a client. The client wants their Google+ gallery incorporated in the app. I use the Picasa API to get a list of albums. So url I use is:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/101422180005529258056
```

If you you put this into a browser and view the XML in an XML viewer, you will see there are 7 "entry" tags. Each of these describes an album.

However, if I hit the link through Ajax in the Phonegap app, I only get back just 2 "entry" tags.

When I do it through php, I also only get back 2 "entry" tags:

```
    $xml = file_get_contents('https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/101422180005529258056');

    file_put_contents('/var/www/my_logs/xml.log', $xml);
```

Why does entering the link directly in a browser give different results to using file_get_contents or Ajax?

Comment: I only see two <entry>s so maybe when you load it in the browser it's authenticating you and showing private entries. Try opening it in an incognito/private browsing window and see what happens.

Comment: Do you get the same results in an incognito / private browsing window? It's possible the request you are seeing in the browser is authenticated while the API request is not.

Comment: yes, it was being authenticated, thanks for help